# Aws Amplify Using Multiple Cognito User Pools in One GraphQL Api

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am new in AWS Amplify and I am try to make simple project.

I have two different frontend(react) projects. One of them for blog readers and one of them for editors.For both applications, I want to use same DynamoDB tables(and use graphql api). But I want to use different user pools for each project. How can I implement this?

I was reading this article - https://medium.com/@fullstackpho/aws-amplify-multi-auth-graphql-public-read-and-authenticated-create-update-delete-1bf5443b0ad1

I know AWS AppSync supports multiple authorization types like cognito, api key ...
But does it support two cognito type?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean cognito group or cognito user_pool by cognito type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per AWS [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/graphql-security-appsync-amplify/), you can use two different **Cognito groups** to access same AppSync API accessing the same DynamoDB table by following ways, which are pretty straight forward;

If you use `aws_auth` directive

```
type Query {
  getPosts:[Post!]! 
  @aws_auth(cognito_groups: ["Bloggers", "Readers"])
}
```

If you use `aws_cognito_user_pools` directive

```
type Query {
  getPosts:[Post!]!
  @aws_api_key @aws_cognito_user_pools(cognito_groups: ["Bloggers", "Readers"])
}
```

Now, if you specifically want two different user pools for your same API and DynamoDB table, then you will have to go little extra mile to achieve this. Following are the steps:

1. Add both of your user pools as **Additional authorization
   providers** in your AppSync settings.
2. Use `@aws_cognito_user_pools` directive with your queries and
   mutation in the schema and the object these queries and mutations are trying to access.
3. This is a tricky one! When you try to access the `$ctx.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId` in your query/mutation resolver, it will throw you null. Because `cognitoIdentityPoolId` is only included in `AWS_IAM` authorization header and not in `AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOLS` [[Ref.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html#aws-appsync-resolver-context-reference-identity)]. However, you can still get user pool ID from `iss` field in `$ctx.identity.claims` and it will look something like `https://cognito-idp.us-xxxx-x.amazonaws.com/us-xxxx-X_XxxXxxXX`. This `us-xxxx-X_XxxXxxXX` is your user pool ID which you will have to parse somehow.
4. After parsing user pool ID, you can filter your users based on
   Cognito pool ID and then granting them the access to the table you
   desire.

Comment: Do both user pools have to be Additional authorization providers? Or can one be the default auth provider and one additional?